# Avoir/Être + participe passé

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical

Parfois je ne comprends pas l'usage de *avoir* + *participe passé*.

Par exemple, pourquoi Jacques Brel a-t-il écrit *L'histoire de ce roi mort de **n'avoir pas pu** te rencontrer* ? Ou encore, puis-je dire *Je voudrais/voulais avoir fait ce travail plus vite* ?

Une telle construction avec des verbes exigeant l'auxiliaire être est-elle correcte ? Par exemple, au lieu de dire *J'aurais aimé aller à la fête*, puis-je dire *J'aimerais être allé à la fête* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En grammaire moderne<sup>1</sup> on dit qu'il s'agit d'un infinitif [accompli](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_accompli/inaccompli), appelé [infinitif passé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitif_pass%C3%A9) en grammaire traditionnelle. Il désigne une action achevée ou un état qui n'est plus valable<sup>2</sup>.

Exemple :

> Ce roi est mort de n'avoir pas pu te rencontrer

signifie « À un certain moment dans le passé, le roi ne pouvait pas rencontrer *te*. Puis, alors que cet état avait pris fin — c'est à dire alors qu'il aurait pu rencontrer *te* —  il est mort. »

À l'inverse *Ce roi est mort de ne pas pouvoir te rencontrer* indique que quand il est mort il ne pouvait toujours pas rencontrer *te*.

De même dans *Je voudrais avoir fait ce travail plus vite* il est sous-entendu que le travail a déjà été fait.

En pratique<sup>3</sup> il s'agit simplement du [temps composé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_compos%C3%A9) correspondant à l'infinitif. Les verbes se composant avec *être* n'en sont absolument pas exclus, mais

> J'aurais aimé aller à la fête

signifie « Au moment où *Je* aurait pu aller à la fête, *Je* aurait aimé y aller ». Alors que

> J'aimerais être allé à la fête

signifie « À présent que *Je* ne peut plus aller à la fête, *Je* aimerait que *Je* y soit allé ».

Ces deux phrases ne sont donc pas équivalentes.

---

<sup>1. Et par *moderne*, je veux dire *sérieuse*. *Linguistique* en fait. ;)</sup>
<sup>2. Bref un [procès](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proc%C3%A8s_%28linguistique%29) accompli.</sup>
<sup>3. En grammaire scolaire...</sup>

Comment: Merci! C'était exactement mon doute avec "j'aurais aimé" et "j'aimerais être...". Dans ma langue cette différence est sensible, je n'étais pas sûre si en français elle serait aussi.

Comment: _Ce roi est mort de n'avoir pas pu te rencontrer._ signifie pour moi que le roi est mort parce qu'il n'a pas pu rencontrer te avant sa mort et _Ce roi est mort de ne pas pouvoir te rencontrer._ signifie que le roi est mort parce qu'il ne pouvait pas rencontrer te au moment de la mort.  De même _J'aurais aimé aller à la fête._ signifie qu'a un moment dans le passé je voulais aller à la fête (et je n'y suis pas allé) et _J'aimerais être allé à la fête._ signifie qu'au moment de l'élocution, je désirais être allé à la fête avant.

Comment: C'est bien mon avis aussi.

Answer (score 4):

Il s'agit de l'[infinitif passé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitif_pass%C3%A9) et exprime l'antériorité.

*J'aimerais être allé à la fête* est correct (tu aurais été à la fête avant le moment de l'énonciation).

Answer (score 0):

En gros : avec l'auxiliaire **avoir** le participe passé s'accorde avec le [COD](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct) si celui-ci est placé avant le verbe :

*L'histoire de ce roi mort de n'avoir pas pu te rencontrer* : COD (*te*) placé après avoir : pas d'accord même si *te* est mis pour une fille.

- Je voudrais avoir fait cette tâche plus vite* tache placé après le verbe : pas d'accord. Mais : *Cette tâche j'aurais voulu l'avoir faite plus vite* : accord avec le COD placé avant le verbe.

Pour approfondir :

- http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire-accord-participe-passe.php
- http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-35623.php

Avec l'auxiliaire **être**  l'accord du participe passé se fait avec le sujet. Et on écrirait *La reine aimerait être allée à la fête*.

http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-20961.php

Comment: J'ai l'impression que la question ne porte pas sur l'accord mais sur l'utilisation de l'infinitif passé.